# Can alternate routes be set up with different viapoints?

Tags: android, skmaps

I am trying to create 3 alternate routes, as in the demo project. After the routes are calculated, I would like to insert different SKViaPoints along each route. Is this possible? SKViaPoint only seems editable at the SKRouteManager level, which would give all alternate routes the same via points.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported - the alternative routes will use the same start, destination and via points as the original route. You can change the routing constraints used for alternatives but not the start/end/viaPoints.

If you need to calculate multiple routes with different settings, call the calculate route API with "[setRouteExposed](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/routing/SKRouteSettings.html#setRouteExposed(boolean))" to false